# modular arithmetic problem (when solving elliptic curves)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Given E: (elliptical curve)

$y^2 = x_3+2x+2 \bmod 17$

Recall: $y^2 = x^3+ax+b$

point $P=(5,1)$

Compute:

$2P = P+P = (5,1)+(5,1)= (x_3,y_3)$

Now the formula used here is 
slope $m = \dfrac{3x_1^2 +a}{2y_1}$

and what they got is $s =  (2 · 1)^{−1} (3 · 5^2 + 2) = 2^{−1} · 9 ≡ 9 · 9 ≡ 13 \bmod 17$

this is what confuses me.

should it not be $(2·1)^{-1}(3 · 5^2 + 2)= 38.5 \bmod 17$ which is 4.5?

Sorry if this may seem trivial, I'm doing a research for a high school project.

The next steps are:

$x_3 = m^2 − x_1 − x_2 = 13^2 − 5 − 5 = 159 ≡ 6 \bmod 17$
$y_3 = m(x_1−x_3) − y_1 = 13(5 − 6) − 1= −14 ≡ 3 \bmod 17$

$(x_3,y_3) = (6,3)$

which I don't understand as well

If someone could enlighten me on this I would be very happy!

Comment: Your $\;x_3\;$ must be, I think, $\;x^3\;$, otherwise this is not an elliptic curve...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2^{-1}=9\pmod{17}\;\;,\;\;3\cdot 5^2=3\cdot 8=7\pmod{17}\implies$$

$$(2\cdot 1)^{-1}(3\cdot 5^2+2)=9(7+2)=9^2=13\pmod{17}$$

BTW, this is **exactly** what you got, since

$$38.5=4.5=\frac92=9\cdot2^{-1}=9\cdot9=13\pmod{13}\ldots$$

Comment: thank you!!! But could you explain to me how does 38.5=4.5 and how does $9⋅2^{-1}=9⋅9$

Comment: I see it now :D

Comment: Well, $\;38.5=4.5\pmod{17}\iff 38.5-4.5=34\;$ is a multiple of $\;17\;$ , which it is. As for $\;2^{-1}\;$: by definition, the inverse of two is an element s.t. when multiplied by two we get one, and indeed: $$2\cdot 9=18=1\pmod{17}\implies 2^{-1}=9$$